How to automatically generate idempotent update lemmas for records in Isabelle
Consider this example:
record r =
  a :: nat
  b :: nat
  

lemma foo: "a r = x ⟹ r ⦇ b := 1 ⦈ = r ⦇ b := 1, a := x ⦈"
  by auto

record R =
  rs :: "nat ⇀ r"

lemma bar: "a r = x ⟹ R ⦇ rs := (rs R) (n ↦ r) ⦈ = R ⦇ rs := (rs R) (n ↦ r ⦇ a := x ⦈) ⦈"
  apply (subgoal_tac "r = r ⦇ a := x ⦈") ― ‹Annoying›
   apply presburger
  apply auto
  done

As expected, foo goes through automatically. However, I also thought bar to be discharged by an apply auto. Instead, because of the partial function update ↦, I have to give this extra subgoal.
That's annoying, because all that's needed is an idempotent update lemma for things to go through automatically:
lemma record_r_idempotent_update_a[simp]: "a r = x ⟹ r ⦇ a := x ⦈ = r"
  by auto

lemma bar': "a r = x ⟹ R ⦇ rs := (rs R) (n ↦ r) ⦈ = R ⦇ rs := (rs R) (n ↦ r ⦇ a := x ⦈) ⦈"
  by auto

How can I automatically generate those idempotent update lemmas? Or is there a better way?
